# How to create Highcharts plotbands along every point in line chart

Tags: javascript, typescript, charts, highcharts

I want to create a linechart with HighCharts that has a plotband along every point of the line. Like so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H10ad.jpg
(They are using HighCharts as well, so it must be possible).

However, I can't seem to manage getting it **for every point specific**. Whenever I add plotbands, it just draws a band using the highest and lowest point like so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwHdT.jpg

How I currently render the chart (note the plotbands part):

```cs
Highcharts.chart('chart', {
      chart: {
        type: 'line',
      },
      title: {
        text: `${this.variable}`,
      },
      credits: {
        enabled: false,
      },
      xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        title: {
          text: "Date"
        },
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: this.unit
        },
        plotBands: [
          {
            color: "orange",
            from: 12,
            to: 14
          },
          {
            color: "orange",
            from: 10,
            to: 13
          } // and so on.
        ]
      },
      tooltip: {
        headerFormat: `<div>Date: {point.key}</div>`,
        pointFormat: `<div>${this.unit}: {point.y}</div>`,
        useHTML: true,
      },
      series: seriesList,
    } as any);
```

So exact example would render a plotband from *10 to 14* along the whole linechart, instead of to different points: one from *12 to 14*, and one from *10 to 13*.

Any ideas as to how I can accomplish this? I have seen something with 'path', but I can't find anything about it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case, you should use `arearange` series instead of plotBand.

**Demo:**
https://www.highcharts.com/demo/arearange-line

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.arearange